# TFS C# - Loading workItemStore returns null or type initializer exception

Tags: c#, wpf, tfs

I am trying to load a TFS WorkItemStore through the following method (see below) which is returning a null value for the WorkItemStore.

```
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServer + "/" + collection));

            //Authenticate with current logged on user
            teamProjectCollection.Authenticate();

            //Setup store and project based on app config settings
            workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

I have also tried to load the WorkItemStore through the following, however this throws the exception: System.TypeInitializationException

```
            workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS WorkItems returns null always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546097/tfs-workitems-returns-null-always)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there are some problems with loading type, perhaps this is due to mismatch versions of .Net used and which were assembly compiled. [Here](http://roadtoalm.com/2011/11/04/tfs-api-workitemstore-is-null-and-throws-nullreferenceexception/) discussed this problem and ways to solve it.

Comment: It appears that this is already done and possibly not the cause/ fix as the inner exception is different ({"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore, Version=10.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."}

Comment: In this case, the problem of the disparity between loaded assembly’s platform, such as the process run as x86, and assembly has platform x64. See how you run the application; take note of the flag "Prefer 32-bit".

Comment: Beautiful, this looks like it's the right area cheers mate :)

Comment: The gist is that you get a helpful error message if you get the service by `workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(teamProjectCollection);`